# Globally change the size of \frac in align environment

Tags: fractions, empheq

I use the [empheq](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/empheq?lang=en) package to display my equations, but I would like to change the size of fractions displayed inside the `align` or `align*` environment, from display style to text style.

I know I can use `tfrac` or `textstyle` to change one of them, but my document is huge and in multiple files, so it would be easier if possible to change the size of all fractions inside `align` environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `etoolbox` package for that. I take the opportunity to mention that the `nccmath`  package defines a `\mfrac` command (medium-sized  fraction,  about `80 % of \displaystyle`), which may be more appropriate in many cases:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[overload]{empheq}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{align*}{\let\oldfrac\frac\def\frac#1#2{\mathchoice
{\tfrac{#1}{#2}}%
{\oldfrac{#1}{#2}}%
{\oldfrac{#1}{#2}}%
{\oldfrac{#1}{#2}}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \frac{a}{b}^{\frac{h}{k}}\neq\dfrac{a}{b}\neq\mfrac{a}{b}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, very efficient, thank you also for the mfrac bit.

Comment: Oops, follow up question, this solution screws up fractional exponents and they are now too big. Is there a way around that?

Comment: I forgot to take this into account, sorry.! I guess a solution might come from `\mathchoice/\mathpalette`, but I'm uneasy with these commands.

Comment: Please see my new solution which (hopefully) takes this problem into account.

Comment: Thanks again, I think there are no problems this time.

Comment: Let's cross our fingers!